# Выкладка списка в два столбца

Tags: css, flexbox, grid

Здравствуйте имеется вот такое меню, которое выкладывается сверху вниз. Сверстать с помощью Flex его не сложно, но проблема в том что приходится ограничивать высоту контейнера и если появится ещё пункты новые элементы появляются уже в трем столбе. Если способ на CSS сверстать данный список в два столба с порядком появления сверху вниз(новые элементы должны появляется снизу).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: контейнеру `display:grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Попробовал, выкладка элементов происходит слева направо а после вниз. А хотелось бы что-бы сначала заполнялся первый столбик а после второй

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow развлекайтесь. вообще и с остальными свойствами гридов ознакомьтесь.

Answer (score 0):

Легче всего с добавлением bootstrap это сделать. Тогда всё сведется к

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      4
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      5
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      6
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```